# Divide area of ellpise but keep proportions

Tags: geometry

I want to divide the area of a ellipse by 2 but want the proportions (scaling) of the ellipse to stay the same.

For example given the following ellipse:

[image: example ellipse]

I can calculate its area with:

```
area = Pi * A * B
```

Given this ellipse has a area of `200` and I want to divide the area by 2 to `100`, how to calculate `A` and `B` so that `A` and `B` stay in the same proportion?

Since there is only one possible solution I think that there is probably some simple formula to this problem.

Does anyone know how to calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a problem of scaling.  When you ask for a way to keep the radii of the elipse in the same proportion, you mean that you want to scale them by the same factor, x.  If S is the scale of the area, then you seek the solution of:

Ax * Bx = A * B * S.  Therefore:

ABx^2 =ABS

x^2 = S

x = S^(1/2)

So if you want to multiply the area of the elipse by 1/2, you want to multiply the lengths of A and B by the square root of 1/2.

Answer (score 2):

Areas scale as the square of linear dimensions.  Divide both $A$ and $B$ by $\sqrt 2$ and the product is divided by $2$.